# I need to select maximum, minimum and average values of certain names in descending order SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one with results of students and one with the courses they are taking.

Table 1: results

> ```
> |student | course | date | grade | examiner | PK:id| 
> |:-------|:-------|:-----|:------|:--------:|:-----:
> |20122222|INFA    | null |   2   |   TC     |  1   | 
> |20123333|INFA    | null |   8   |   TC     |  2   | 
> |20122222|INFA    | null |   4   |   VB     |  3   | 
> |20122222|INFA    | null |   6   |   VB     |  4   | 
> |20123333|INFB    | null |   10  |   null   |  5   | 
> |20124444|INFB    | null |   4   |   VB     |  6   | 
> |20121234|INFA    | null |   8   |   VB     |  7   | 
> |20121234|INFC    | null |   8   |   GV     |  8   |
> ```

PK stands for primary key, also I left out the dates because they are irrelevant

Table 2:course

> ```
> |PK:code|     name      |coordinator|
> |:------|:-------------:|:---------:|
> |INFA   |Programming    |VB         |
> |INFB   |Databases      |VB         |           
> |INFC   |WebApplications|BD         |
> |INFD   |OO Programming |null       |
> ```

now the goal is to get the highest, lowest and average grade per course name sorted in descending order. Now I've tried several things but I can't seem to get the output right. The output should be:

> ```
> |name           |highest|lowest|average|
> |:-------------:|:------|:-----|:------|
> |WebApplications|8      |8     |8.0    |
> |Databases      |10     |4     |7.0    |
> |Programming    |8      |2     |5.6    |
> ```

But I cant get them sorted right on the course name

Comment: okay, the tablemaking did not go as expected, god this is messy

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They do not use the same sql dialect.
_Sorted in descending order_ OF WHAT?

Comment: title says "of certain names" I see no criteria which defines how we determine those certain names.  maybe those that don't have a null coordinator?

Comment: Descending order does not affect Min, Max and Avg. please state your question more clearly.

Comment: Order by avg desc? It's the only column in the expected results in descending order.  Assumption on my part but seems logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the query should look like this:

```
SELECT min(grade) AS lowest, max(grade) AS highest, avg(grade) AS average 
FROM results 
GROUP BY course 
ORDER BY average DESC.
```

If you want to have the course names in the same query, join results:

```
SELECT course.name, min(grade) AS lowest, max(grade) AS highest, avg(grade) AS average 
FROM results
JOIN course on results.course = course.code 
GROUP BY course     
ORDER BY average DESC
```

.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a course w/o results and you want to display it, I'd use a left join course to results and then basic aggregation functions.  and I assumed descending order of average.

```
SELECT c.name, max(R.grade) highest, min(R.grade) lowest, avg(R.grade) mAverage
FROM Course C
LEFT JOIN Results R
 on C.Code = R.Course
WHERE C.Coordinator is not null
--Not sure if SQL server allows you to group by columns not in select; I know mySQL will if group by extensions are enabled.
GROUP BY C.Code, C.Name
ORDER BY mAverage DESC
```

Comment: OP might also want to throw some [`IFNULL`s](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) in there to handle those cases where courses don't have results.  Might also be faster to group by `C.Code` as it's likely a PK.  Not sure I understand why we're filtering out courses without coordinators, though...

Comment: Course OO Programming wasn't in the results.  may ave been because an inner join would eliminate it since no results record but since the title said filter out some of the names,but no criteria, I made an assumption.  Not sure why IfNull would be needed. max/min would still yield that and null would be ignored in the average.  Agree with grouping on c code as it would have the same effect in mySQL; but the syntax would error if this was SQL server (or current version of mySQL unless group by extensions were enabled), so ... group by name.

Comment: That's interesting about SQL server - what's the syntactical difference between c.code and c.name? (The IFNULL comment was just to handle possible future cases where the aggregate functions don't have anything to calculate after the left join and would normally return null - might be preferable to return 0 or 100 or "N/A" or whatever. I was looking at OP's solution as an *example* of correct values, not a complete target solution.  If this is just a homework question then they're totally unnecessary and the `where` clause make total sense, though as you said, I suspect inner join was intended)

Comment: mySQL's group by extensions allow you to group by non aggregated fields thus you can group by c.code; w/o c.name. SQL Server I suppose would let you group by C.Code and C.Name, but it must have both as C.name can't be unaggregated in the select and excluded from the group by.  ifnull is specific to mySQL and since we don't know which I'd prefer to leave them as null.  Coalesce would work however... but again I prefer the nulls; they are more meaningful to me.  I can't 'N/A' as they are numeric fields; but point taken.   More info needed to fully address and since we've had no more input...